# Reseting value of variable just for specific condition and fixed value for everything else

Tags: c++, loops, variables, if-statement, constants

I'm making an update for a game.

In the game, there are units with different number of weapons. Like as: Baneblade Super Heavy Tank with (Baneblade Cannoon, Demolisher Cannon and Heavy Bolter).
And some weapons have special weapon traits and others don't. Weapons with zero traits are shown as "" (not null, only space).
In my example, Baneblade Cannon is `""`, Demolisher Cannon is `"Siege"`, Heavy Bolter is `""`.
What I want to do is: If a weapon have `"Siege"` trait, enemy cover will be ignored and it will be `0`.

I can do it as:

```
for (int w = 0; w < 4; w++)
{
    ... // some other codes

    int nDefCover = g_arrTerrainTypes[m_arrUnitEx[nDef].nTerrain].nCover; //     to reset nCover
    const auto& traits = m_arrUnitEx[nAtt].unit.pType->arrWeapons[w]->strTraits;

    // I check if a number w weapon has "Siege" string
    if (traits.Find("Siege") != std::string::npos) 
    {
        // nCover gives the value of enemy's cover.
        g_arrTerrainTypes[m_arrUnitEx[nDef].nTerrain].nCover = 0;
    }

    ... // some other weapon trait codes

    if (traits.Find("") != std::string::npos)
    {
        g_arrTerrainTypes[m_arrUnitEx[nDef].nTerrain].nCover = nDefCover;
    }
}
```

After this, I have to reset the `nCover` value or from now on, all weapons will ignore cover bonus for enemy. I want just Siege weapon to ignore cover.

So, I use `g_arrTerrainTypes[m_arrUnitEx[nDef].nTerrain].nCover = nDefCover;` to reset `nCover` to actual value for other weapons.

But system works like this:
It looks at first weapon. It's `""`, so it changes `nCover` to its original value.
It looks at second weapon and it is `"Siege"`, so it changes `nCover` to `0`.
It looks at third weapon and it is `""`, so it changes `nCover` to its original value.
In the end, `nCover` returns as its original value and `Siege` weapon traits means nothing. It is like `0` OR  `0` OR `1` situation.
If a unit has a `Siege` weapon in its last weapon slot this code can work but weapons order changes with every unit.
How can I change `nCover` to `0` for `Siege` weapon but for every other situation, change to its original value without changing `Siege` weapon `nCover`? I should do that with a loop but couldn't found where to put it and which loop I should use yet.

Comment: why do you want to change the value at all? I mean the players cover does not depend on what is aiming at him. It is just that certain weapons ignore that value (whatever it is and without having to modify it)

Comment: in other words: Why "... trait, enemy cover will be ignored and it will be "0" " and not simply " enemy cover will be ignored." ? Why setting the value to 0 when anyhow it is ignored?

Comment: I have entered this process at last stage. I wasn't there when they were establishing the system like this... In the game, cover bonuses are  like 10, 25, 30, 50 (at most). So if they are 0, Siege weapon calculate its damage as if there is no cover. Your saying is same actually. If I don't reset "cover", all weapons will ignore covers. It's not about changing its value to "0" or "ignoring it". It is about resetting value in proper time.

Comment: If you loop over your weaponr, you can compute cover, compute damage (restore cover for next weapons).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for idea. I will try to do that. By the way, thanks for editing code too, it gave me an another idea.

Comment: I haven't written for loop in the beginning of code. Actually, there was a for loop already to loop over every weapon and access it's features. But that doesn't work for what I want. After changing value of nCover for 2nd weapon, I have to check for other weapons too and if any one of them is "", nCover will be overriden. I couldn't figured out how it can be done with additional loop...

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you please write your answer? Where should I put a loop and which loop do you mean? By the way I've edited my question and actually there was a for loop in the beginning of original code. It's for looping over unit's each weapon to access it's features (strength, health, cover etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in a weird way I couldn't imagine...

First, I've removed nDefCover definition from top of the code and from ifs.

Then I have written a definition at above of `const auto& traits` as: `nFinalAccuracy = max(0, min(100, nFinalAccuracy));`


After that, I've added `nDefCover`'s value to the `nFinalAccuracy`'s value for `Siege` and other necessary weapons.

Final code is:

```
for (int w = 0; w < 4; w++)
{
  nFinalAccuracy = max(0, min(100, nFinalAccuracy));
  const auto& traits = m_arrUnitEx[nAtt].unit.pType->arrWeapons[w]->strTraits;

  if (traits.Find("Siege") != std::string::npos)
  {
      nFinalAccuracy = max(0, min(100, (nFinalAccuracy + nDefCover)));
  }  

  if (traits.Find("Siege") != std::string::npos && traits.Find("Titankiller") != std::string::npos)
  {
      nFinalAccuracy = 100;
  }

  if (traits.Find("Siege") != std::string::npos && traits.Find("Terror") != std::string::npos)
  {
      nFinalAccuracy = max(0, min(100, (nFinalAccuracy + nDefCover)));
  }

  if (m_arrUnitEx[nDef].unit.pType->nUnitClass == UC_AIRCRAFT && traits.Find("AA") != std::string::npos)
  {
      nFinalAccuracy = 100;
  }

  if (traits.Find("Terror") != std::string::npos)
  {   
      m_arrUnitEx[nDef].unit.nMorale.actual = m_arrUnitEx[nDef].unit.nMorale.actual - 10;
  }
}
```

I assume it works like; A weapon fires, calculates initiative for enemy's and player's unit, apply damage for both side and continues to next weapon and before checking traits for other weapons, it resets the `nFinalAccuracy` to original value.

It seems like code works for any weapon so far.

Answer (score 0):

I mean that you should compute damage for each weapon, and not afterward,
so you should have something like:

```
for (auto& weapon : m_arrUnitEx[nAtt].unit.pType->arrWeapons)
{
    // if (distance(nAtt, nDef) > weapon.range) continue;
    dealDamage(weapon, nDef);
}
```

with:

```
void dealDamage(Weapon& weapon, int nDef)
{
    const auto& traits = weapon.strTraits;
    int nDefCover = g_arrTerrainTypes[m_arrUnitEx[nDef].nTerrain].nCover;
    if (traits.Find("Siege") != std::string::npos) 
    {
        nDefCover = 0;
    }

    m_arrUnitEx[nDef].hitPoints -= computeDamage(weapon, nDefCover);
    --weapon.ammo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will try something like that. But actually same code was in the code already (for loop for weapons, nDefCover declaration). There is no ammo count but it's ok, I got what you mean. Damage function is in another function though, called ApplyDamage(int nUnit int nHP). I need like; storing nCover for Siege weapons but restoring it for everything else "at the same time"... Thank you again.